# Como encontrar a soma de dois números num array que coincidam com o valor de entrada

Tags: php, loop, matemática

Como fazer isso sem a necessidade de fazer dois laços.

Método de exemplo:

```
function getPairNumbers($array, $valor) {
  //aqui viria o método
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode testar cada posição, do início e do fim do array, e ir testando cada posição, e ir incrementando, na medida que for encontrando o valor desejado:

```
<?php
function getPairNumbers($numbers, $target)
{
    $result = array();
    sort($numbers);
    $high = count($numbers) - 1;

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($numbers);) {
        if ($numbers[$i] + $numbers[$high] == $target) {
            $result[0] = $numbers[$i];
            $result[1] = $numbers[$high];
            break;
        }

        if ($numbers[$i] + $numbers[$high] < $target) {
            $i++;
         }

        if ($numbers[$i] + $numbers[$high] > $target) {
            $high--;
        }

        if ($high <= $i) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

$arr = getPairNumbers(array(1,4,5,15,30,25,20,0,13), 18);

print_r($arr);
```